# How to Delete All files But Excluding Specific Files (Batch File)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

I know there are questions here like this before but in my case there are special conditions in specifying the files to be excluded in the "delete" operation.

Filename examples:

A_001.xml
A_002.xml
B_001.xml
B_002.xml
B_003.xml
C_009.xml
D_002.xml

The files above are in one directory and I need to delete all files but retain one copy of each file with the highest counter in filename which are A_002.xm, B_003.xml, C_009.xml and D_002.xml.

Is this possible? I'm new in batch file creation so please help me.. I already know how to delete files and even exclude a specific file extension but I don't know what to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
::
:: establish target directory
:: initialise PREFIX to a name that's invalid in a filename
::
SET target=.
SET prefix=:
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%i IN (
 'dir /b/a-d/o-n "%target%\*_*.xml'
 ) DO (
IF !prefix!==%%i ECHO DEL "%target%\%%i_%%j"
SET prefix=%%i
)
```

This solution relies on the presence of "_" in the names of the *xml files in the target directory. I tested it on some dummy files in my batch-development directory, hence I used `.` for `the current directory`

The DIR command produces a list of the files in the target directory that match the pattern `*_*.xml` The`/b` switch means `filename only`, `/a-d` means `no directory names, even if they match` and `/o-n` means `in the reverse order of name` Therefore, the names will appear with the highest numeric value of the part after `_` first.

The FOR reads this output and assigns the prefix to `%%i` and the remainder of the filename to `%%j` Since `prefix` is initialised to an invalid-in-filenames character, it cannot possibly match `%%i` for the first file encountered, so the `DEL` will not be executed. The last-encountered prefix will then be stored. Only if the next filename has a matching prefix will the `DEL` be executed

Note that I've inserted the `ECHO` keyword before the `DEL`. This is a safety device in case of error. The PROPOSED `DEL` operation will be reported to the screen, not EXECUTED. Once you're satisfied that the batch is correct, remove the `ECHO` and the delete operation will proceed.

Point to be observed:

- Some editors are quite cavalier about stripping or retaining trailing
  spaces. Normally, this is harmless but trailing spaces on a `SET`
  command in batch can cause chaos.

Comment: To avoid issues by trailing spaces you can just enclose the argument to `set` in quotes: `set "target=."`. Any trailing spaces after that won't be part of the variable value.

Comment: Yes - you can also parenthesise the SET `(set var=whatever)` which I commonly do when it's important to delete the variable `(set var=)` but I feel that it's normally overkill. Perhaps I should explicitly use the belt-and-braces form where it's critical - good point. You only ever get caught by that particular trap once though - if it happens more than once, maybe you should consider changing your occupation rather than simply your editor...

Comment: ... or the language ;) Although I find it sometimes a nice hobby to try writing robust and reliable batch files.

Comment: I agree there is no specific reason to do this in batch except the challenge of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set newprefix=_
for /F %%a in ('dir /on /b /a-d *.xml') do (
for /F "delims=_" %%i in ("%%a") do (
   IF NOT *%%i*==*!newprefix!* (
   for /F %%q in ('dir /on /b /a-d %%i*.xml') do set lastitem=%%q
   attrib +r !lastitem!  > NUL
   del /s /q %%i*.xml 1>NUL 2>NUL 
   attrib -r !lastitem!  > NUL
   set newprefix=%%i
   )
)
)
```

For each prefix of xml file, lists all the files with the prefix in question to get the last one in the list. Then mark the last one read only. Delete all with given pattern except read only. Reset read only flag and do over for next prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much joojaa for your answer. I did mark your answer as useful but unfortunately I must choose Peter's answer as my accepted answer for a more clearer explanation and simpler code. Thanks again mate :)

Comment: Sure no problem, however I considered not posting the script since Peter already posted an answer. Its just that I feel Peter did not really answer the question directly. Peters code only deals with not deleting the highest number, same as i do with 4 lines in the inner loop (using a trick). However it does not deal with automatically searching each set and handling it. So while nicely annotated does not really answer the question as asked. as you still need to fix the prefix and so on for each group. But this is also the reason why I dint bother to annotate the task very well.